# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'. Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There are many people on stack overflow asking to solve this question but there is no solution that has worked. My application is an MVC and a Web Api. Testing locally on Visual Studio works fine.

However, when i deploy it, it gives me the error, No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable1' from content with media type 'text/html'.
Exception Details: System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'.

Here is the code below.

```
WebApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myweburl/WEBAPI/api/"); 
WebApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
WebApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
//WebApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

I don't understand why the error says the server puts out text/html. But when i tested it locally and it is JSON formatting.

Does anyone know if it is a result of net target framework as well? This is running the NET target framework of 4.6.1 for both the web api and mvc. I changed my information in the web.config to 4.0 but it didn't work as well.

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the API endpoint and not an MVC view? If it appears to work locally I would check that the setup of the environment you have deployed to (things like the bindings and DNS etc). Also what is the signature/ code of the API endpoint you think you are calling?

Comment: @CraigH you were right! It was the permissions of the server that did not allowed the permissions of a web api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there was a firewall denying my permissions and generating the text/HTML instead of querying from the database. However, there is little support to be able to figure out what is the error. My suggestion is to print out the information that is being passed through from the Web Api and then see if it a permission denied by the firewall.